# Analytical Solution to a linear PDE with delta function like source term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fundamental-solution

I have a time-independent Vlasov equation with source term in $R^2$:
$$v\cdot\partial{f}/\partial{x}+\partial{f}/\partial{v}=s(x,v)$$
where $s(0,0)=500$, else $s(x,v)=0$.
And I was wondering how to achieve the analytical solution for this PDE because the source term is not the pure delta function(which value should be infinity).

Comment: You should use $\cdot$ instead of $*$ unless you actually mean convolution (which doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will modify it.